# How to build out table for DB using OrderedDict pulled from CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, peewee, ordereddict

I am doing a project for section 4 on TeamTreehouse.com tech degree for python. I have gone through the section 4 within 2 days, passed all the quizes and did all the code challenges but I still can not find out how to write data to a DB file using peewee and orderedDict after reading info from a CSV file.  I have read the orderedDict documentation and peewee's but I cant find how to write an OrderedDict to a DB.

I have tried searching documentations and revisiting training videos on teamtreehouse.com and can not find any examples of this at all.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import datetime
import sys
import csv

from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('inventory.db')


class Product(Model):
    content = TextField()
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    product_name = TextField(unique=True)
    product_price = TextField()
    product_quantity = TextField()
    date_updated = DateTimeField(datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        database = db

def migrate_data():
    with open('inventory.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        keys = next(reader)
        #ordered = ([OrderedDict(zip(keys,row)) for row in reader ])
        print('\n\n')
        print([OrderedDict(zip(keys,row)) for row in reader ])
        print('\n\n')



def initialize():
    """ Initialize an Sqlite database called inventory.db."""
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([Product], safe=True)


def create_model():
    """ Create a model called Product that the Peewee ORM will use to 
build the database. 
The Product model should have five attributes: product_id, product_name, 
product_quantity, 
product_price. Use PeeWee's built in primary_key functionality for the 
product_id field,
 so that each product will have an automatically generated unique 
identifier."""
    productname = ('product_name')
```

The expected result for this question would be writing the OrderedDict that has been built from reading the CSV file, to sqlite file using peewee. You can download the CSV file AND FULL python code from my github (Yeransian) and under "Treehouse-Project4"

Any help to get me over this slump would be amazing! The faster I get back to learning the better. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a csv which is like a table, should translate to a `list`
 of `dicts`. The most straightforward (although not the most efficient) way would be to loop over this list and [create](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.create) an instance of the `Product`.

```
# something along these lines
def save_list_to_db(list_of_dicts_from_csv): 
    for single_product_dict in list_of_dicts_from_csv:
        Product.create(content = single_product_dict['content'],
                       id = single_product_dict['id'], ....
                       )
```

As said, this is not a very efficient way, as it opens a connection to the database for every `Product.create(...)`. Bulk inserts are more efficient. You can read about this [here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html?highlight=insert_many#bulk-inserts). Good luck!